# A rock is thrown into the air from a 40 foot deck with an initial velocity of 112 ft/s. What is the maximum height the rock will reach?

Tags: projectile-motion

I wasn’t very sure where to start with this one, so I tried looking online to find an example problem. From the ones I looked through, it seems you need at least one of the following variables - maximum height or time in the air. I was not given any of these, so I tried calculating initial velocity first, but then realized you can’t since you’re missing acceleration and time.

So my question is how would you find the maximum height and initial velocity with these unknowns?

Comment: Eh... the acceleration is given. (The acceleration of gravity on Earth, $\approx 9.81 m/s^2$, facing down.) Also, why are you calculating initial velocity when that is given ($112 ft/s$, you may need to convert into $m/s$)

Comment: Correction, I tried to find VELOCITY. That was a typo on my part.

Comment: This is a typical problem and all the equations you will ever need are those five: https://www.ncl.ac.uk/academic-skills-kit/numeracy-maths-statistics/mechanics/ ("SUVAT" equations). If you know three of: displacement ($s$), initial velocity ($u$), final velocity ($v$), acceleration ($a$) and/or time ($t$) - you can find the remaining two. Notice that, in this case, you have given $u$, $a$ and $v$ and are (pretty much, though not quite!) asked to find $s$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
Use $$v^2=u^2+2(-g)H_{max}$$

Where $u=112 ft/s, g=32.17 ft/s^2$

At maximum height $v=0 ft/s$

In this case $H_{max }$ is with the deck as a reference line.